# Why the performance of modPow method of BigInteger decreases as the number of threads increases?

Tags: java, benchmarking, biginteger

The performance of modPow method of BigInteger decreases as the number of threads increases.
The member variables are thread-level and should not interfere with each other.

benchmark test code

```
package com.talkingdata.opal.integration.symmetry.test;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Threads;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

@Threads(3)
@BenchmarkMode({Mode.AverageTime})
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 3, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 3, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class BigInetgerTest {

  @Setup
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("init:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    m = new BigInteger(
        "23102926163894804087468123845710955522238616569973353666239281949381051504551107360224306915645591442126969367657705430485746630194363134197282145402137496269572666746400440267844001070710891170019593928247889219946313036136160469214589902672935747681518472609981550373853654832707994073047370743370794391428670156851861824033969965168801027151081979879199373777395119996586955588065252135175109759281180503879410538517857534026402833729199373986365997415163253052422745035555497837505700225170627737903279421848273562122194826772338221878855543785028138290857341786447649895870946906474600198233990840527227839018238");
    ki = new BigInteger(
        "15496440288162419743268865114718257026885852313393508981474715221247140659575649380767994818172205420737192128574550076158981589552379214454159707302643163377814248952866015163322720213833249792410504477853431675639144135121119309034212137557381478542811241062421295329899396524651982321353860248201123787675894854005120584982976827832766435148510565563246764483917116360298494738360322791669514381959902756409009769298597889063173534343555581813116322134507007988747435656868578866321886606974476570934420927075393527376424244368884854766550653763850949818570822087960406683778581342937865788766804181937608463131857");
    p = new BigInteger(
        "27490896491489933992335324412569064612936644033659513179033017851327970216503296052491992976141549398201926199899588430101761196079157975703190131823229250106593153163655759253193643838508347060103568847805004457541248662429424153065534929351429845548643935657179253524125542257935535470543855771942241949526306435288473106976439156680014892693560941587038760913532303771463223029959086784861633301252525277074123146731837131167003251939861023095487264155821033565607389379286168868855925138310714581578711756536246844281245559500184650926517289810292587014812981652258232654229507008153238338553726865482037835778213");
  }

  private BigInteger m;
  private BigInteger ki;
  private BigInteger p;


  @Benchmark
  public void modPow(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(m.modPow(ki, p));
  }



}
```

my machine info:

[image: machine info]

The number of threads is far from the CPU kernel limit number.

main method:

```
package com.talkingdata.opal.integration.symmetry.main;

import com.talkingdata.opal.integration.symmetry.test.BigInetgerTest;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

public class BigIntegerMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    String name = BigInetgerTest.class.getName();
    String s = LocalTime.now().toString();
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        .include(name)
        .forks(1)
        .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
  }

}
```

Benchmark result:
1 thread  :4754.657us/op
20 thread :26436.544us/op

```
 thread number:1
 Benchmark              Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
 BigInetgerTest.modPow  avgt    5  4754.657 ± 310.503  us/op
 thread number:2
 Benchmark              Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
 BigInetgerTest.modPow  avgt    5  4765.872 ± 219.227  us/op
 thread number:4
 Benchmark              Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
 BigInetgerTest.modPow  avgt    5  5786.041 ± 220.751  us/op
 thread number:20
 Benchmark              Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
 BigInetgerTest.modPow  avgt    5  26436.544 ± 566.881  us/op
```

And I add jmh stackprofiler in the case of 20 threads.
here is result:

```
Secondary result "com.talkingdata.opal.integration.symmetry.test.BigInetgerTest.modPow:·stack":
Stack profiler:

....[Thread state distributions]....................................................................
 93.0%         RUNNABLE
  4.5%         TIMED_WAITING
  2.5%         WAITING

....[Thread state: RUNNABLE]........................................................................
 88.0%  94.6% java.math.BigInteger.oddModPow
  4.5%   4.9% java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0
  0.3%   0.3% java.math.MutableBigInteger.divWord
  0.1%   0.1% jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.unpark
  0.1%   0.1% java.math.BigInteger.materialize
  0.0%   0.0% java.math.BigInteger.leftShift
  0.0%   0.0% java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000
  0.0%   0.0% jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke
  0.0%   0.0% java.lang.Class.cast
  0.0%   0.0% java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger.getAndDecrement

....[Thread state: TIMED_WAITING]...................................................................
  4.5% 100.0% java.lang.Object.wait

....[Thread state: WAITING].........................................................................
  2.5% 100.0% jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park
```

I got the flame diagram with [asyn-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler)

[image: flame diagram]

Comment: The peformance of *anything* decreases as the number of threads increases.  There is only so much CPU power available, and it is multiplexed between the threads. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: You mean that the use of multithreading increases the time per operation, but it increases the total throughput, even if it does not use full CPU cores?

Comment: According to my information, E5 2630v4 has 10 cores (20 threads), not 20 (40t), perhaps there is some mistake there, IMO you should double check this (maybe 2 sockets?). Also keep in mind reduced turbo under multi-core loads, and shared resources such as LLC. It may be interesting to see a graph of the speed for 1 to 20 threads, to see when large changes happen.

Comment: @victor - No.  He means that on a machine with N cores, you won't get any speedup with more than N threads doing CPU intensive work.  Another point is that your benchmark could well be memory intensive rather than CPU intensive.  So you could be seeing the results of cache or memory bandwidth limitations.

Comment: (I note that you are already starting to see non-linearity at 4 threads ...)

Comment: @StephenC I agree with you. Performance suffers when some of the CPU is idle. That means it's not CPU intensive. How do I detect if  application is memory intensive?Are there any indicators?

Comment: In a memory intensive scenario the CPU pipeline stalls.  That *doesn't* lead to CPUs showing as idle.  If you are *seeing* CPUs idle, then the cause of the slowdown is something else.

Comment: But ... how do you detect it?  I don't think there is an easy way.   And it probably wouldn't help you solve the problem anyway.  (The implementation of `BigInteger` is what it is ....)

Comment: In my case, the CPUs are not idle.

Comment: (If nos threads >= nos cores and you do observe that some CPUs are idle, that implies that there is a concurrency or I/O bottleneck in the code you are testing.  Not your scenario ... but I am just pointing this out.)